# redirect a domain with http to different domain with https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I have a question with regards to redirecting a domain with http to a different domain with https.
I have installed an SSL certificate on my domain `www.some.com`  ( it isn't wildcard, so it is correct only for www, and without it on my domain ), so if i go on `https://www.some.com` or `http://www.some.com` all work correctly, all request are redirected to `https://www.some.com` .

Then i have bought other domain, for example,  as test.org, so if i want redirect this domain to `https://some.com` browser alert me that SSL certificate is only valid for some.com .

Correct rewrite condition that i have inserted was:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.org$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.org$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/some\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: No need to escape the characters in the URL you are redirecting to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://some.com/ [R=301,L]
```

or with all the final URL (test.org/xxxx/yyy...)

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://some.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But, I don't really know what is your problem, or error...